# Chemnum commands not recognized

Tags: texstudio, chemnum

I am writing my Master thesis in Latex (Texstudio). I need to draw a lot of molecules and want to number them throughout the whole thesis. 
For some strange reason, the package chemnum isn't working. The commands are highlighted in red when I compile the file and the output isn't the right one.

[image]

I *really* need that package. I have even checked the chemnum.cwl  in the autocompletion list in the settings to get recognized in every document but that doesn't help either.

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4 paper,oneside,openright,titlepage]{book}
%\usepackage{mathptmx} se vuoi usare times new roman
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemscheme,chemfig,chemformula,epstopdf}
\usepackage{upgreek} 
\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\usepackage{textgreek} 
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek} 

\begin{document}
The first-line therapy for drug-susceptible TB consists in two months of isoniazid \refcmpd{isoniazid}, rifampicin \refcmpd{rifampicin}, pyrazinamide \refcmpd{pyrazinamide} , and ethambutol \refcmpd{ethambutol} following with four months of rifampicin and isoniazid (2HRZE/4HR).(figure \ref{first-line})
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \replacecmpd[TMP1]{isoniazid}
    \replacecmpd[TMP2]{rifampicin}
    \replacecmpd[TMP3]{pyrazinamide}
    \replacecmpd[TMP4]{ethambutol}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{first-line-treatment}
    \caption{First-line drugs}
    \label{first-line}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Link to the eps file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ordl0cjj2z004h4/first-line-treatment.eps?dl=0

Output of the figure 1.1
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you installed `chemnum` correctly (i.e. you can use it in other document)? Does it throw an error when you load it without using it? Have you loaded `chemnum` in your preamble?

Comment: I have loaded chemnum in the preamble with the command \usepackage{chemnum}

Comment: Does it throw errors like "`chemnum.sty` not found"?

Comment: it is impossible to debug a screenshot, please show a small test file and show the exact error message that you get in the log file.

Comment: @JouleV no, it doesn't

Comment: @DavidCarlisle here it is the code

Comment: first error (chemmacros)  Warning: You haven't loaded any package for upright Greek  letters or no unique choice was possible. Either load one of packages specified in the manual or  select a chemgreek mapping manually.

Comment: Good luck with your thesis :-) "in bocca al lupo".

Comment: Without an example figure to check I do not know if it is enough but the minimum to get a pdf is to include a package to provide closure of the warning e.g. \usepackage{upgreek}

Comment: @KJO I added the link to the file and added to the code the strings
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}
As it is said on the chemmacros manual. Now the problem with the greek letters isn't showing up but it still doesn't recognize the commands.

Comment: @Sebastiano crepi

Comment: Vittoria Thanks for file & update that allows us to do a test run as if on your setup. I confirm that having placed eps in the same folder as the mwe & removing the folder/name It runs well. That is on first pass there are ?? but change on second pass to read as 1 2 3 4 the unresolved item is the last one \cite but thats understandable with just a snippet So If you have that part working the remaining issue is 1st Are you getting TWO successful runs so as to resolve cross-refs. Subfolders can interfere with processing refs (that is why to avoid). Try with eps bib & tex in fresh folder (NO aux)

Comment: @KJO Thank you for your precious help to the OP.

Comment: @KJO thank you for your help. I have moved the eps file from the folder ChemDraw/eps to the folder where the main file is. However, it still doesn't work.  
I have read the "Active competion file" and for the chemnum package I can read:
------------------- Package #chemnum.cwl: ---------------------
 possible commands
  normal: \cmpd, \thecmpdmain, \chemnum, \chemnumdate, \chemnuminfo, \chemnumversion
 special def commands
 special treatment commands
 option Commands: 
 kinds: \cmpd(::), \thecmpdmain(::), \chemnum(::), \chemnumdate(::), 
(part 1 of 2)

Comment: @KJO 
\chemnuminfo(::), \chemnumversion(::)
 all commands: ; \thecmpdmain

Is it normal? It seems to me that some commands are missing in the list

(part 2 of 2)

Comment: when you moved the file to main folder did you remove the paths thus \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{ChemDraw/eps/first-line-treatment} needs to become simply  \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{first-line-treatment} also if you have a problem run and make such a significant file location change it is wise to use tools > clean auxiliary files before the next two pass attempt. for what its worth I also see using your mwe above the unrecognised coloring but it does not affect the outcome (I still get in log window a warning no greekupright) but not affecting a good 2nd pass with the "mwe as it stands"

Comment: view > show > log messages only shows 2 bad box and 4 warnings including the upright greek one for me those are not a reason to not get a pdf result, once you add or remove items the errors can change and if your main file has other references with errors its important to clear the first significant one

Comment: If I add in the four lines per your comments  \usepackage{upgreek} \usepackage{chemmacros} \usepackage{textgreek} \chemsetup{greek=textgreek} into the mwe  before \begin{document} the results are better and appear in one run with only three perfectly acceptable warnings and a single bad box due to the width of the eps (acceptable 20...pt too wide)

Comment: With respect to red colouring recognition of commands is in some ways similar to the way a spellchecker works so if a word is highlighted it does not mean it is wrong it is just a warning that the system is not aware of the word so to remove the colors you can configure > show advanced options (bottom left tick box) Custom highlighting > additional commands and enter \chemsetup (then newline) \refcmpd (and also) \replacecmpd If you now close the tex file & reload the colours are gone it's a cosmetic issue it does not aid autocomplete but stops them showing it does not make the command not work

Comment: @KJO I've done what you have said. Everything goes fine but in the picture there are still the temporary labels.

Comment: Ok now I understand what your issue is the replacement of the TMP tags is done by an external call so 1) you need to check you have -shell-escape in your configured command for pdfLaTeX 2) you may need to remove epstopdf from the \usepackage{chemscheme… you could put it on its own with a comment e.g. % \usepackage{epstopdf} so can easily include for some runs if needed 3) to make the change in the EPS you may also need \usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf} that is all based on problems others had but for me changed the TMP1 to a bold 1 beyond that I don't normally use chemfig

Comment: @KJO IT WORKS! Thank you very much

Comment: Great now you may be able to remove / revert any surplus advice / changed bits one at a time if you wish :-)